# How is metaclass.__call__ working in this case?

Tags: python, call, super, metaclass

```
import inspect

class meta(type):
   def __new__(cls, t_name, bases, argdict):
       print "inside meta __new__"
       return super(meta, cls).__new__(cls, t_name, bases, argdict)

   def __init__(self, t_name, bases, argdict): 
       print "inside __init__ of meta"

   def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
       print "*************************"
       print "inside __call__ of meta"
       print cls, args, kwargs #--> cls is A
       # How cls is passed as __call__ does not take cls param? through super/how? Why super requires cls?
       inst = super(meta, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs) # why no cls to call? how super works here
       #inst = type.__call__(cls, *args, **kwargs) # this works well
       print inst, "instance inside meta"
       print "*************************"
       return inst


class A(object):
    __metaclass__ = meta # this line triggers metaclass

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print "inside A __new__"
        print cls, args, kwargs # we get cls here as A
        inst = super(A, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        print inst, "instance inside A"
        return inst

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print "inside A __init___"
        self.attr = args[0]

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print "inside A __call__ "
        print self, args, kwargs



a = A("simple arg") # this is type(A).__call__(A, ... ) ==           meta.__call__(A, ...)
print a
a("param")  # type(a).__call__(a), ...
print type(A)
```

`OUTPUT`

```
inside meta __new__
inside __init__ of meta
*************************
inside __call__ of meta
<class '__main__.A'> ('simple arg',) {}
inside A __new__
<class '__main__.A'> ('simple arg',) {}
<__main__.A object at 0x7ff0010f2c10> instance inside A
inside A __init___
<__main__.A object at 0x7ff0010f2c10> instance inside meta
*************************
<__main__.A object at 0x7ff0010f2c10>
inside A __call__ 
<__main__.A object at 0x7ff0010f2c10> ('param',) {}
<class '__main__.meta'>
<type 'type'>
True
```

I have some questions embedded inside code [not putting here as it will make question more longer].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument of a method is the instance. An instance of a metaclass is a class, which is why we name the argument `cls`.

`super()` needs the instance so that it can follow MRO properly. Its methods are already bound to an appropriate instance and so don't need the instance to be passed explicitly.

Comment: Thanks ignacio , first part I understood why we name it `cls` . but second part is not clear , may b stupid questions  `does type() triggers type.__call__  ` like all other callables? ? and does `__new__`  has explicit requirement for cls thats why we provide it ?

Comment: All callables involve the `__call__()` method, directly or otherwise. `__new__()` is [defined that way](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__).